Is "Couldn't be able to" incorrect english
I think it is incorrect but dont have enough knowledge of grammar and definitions to explain why to a friend.

Why does it sound incorrect to you?

In the appropriate sentence it is perfectly valid.

Perhaps so, @RohitGupta, but it’s an odd collocation nonetheless. And syntactic validity is distinct from idiomaticity.

Consider that couldn't means was unable to; then explain why you need a way of saying "was unable to be able to."  If you have a good explanation for this, then you have a context in which it is correct to say "couldn't be able to."  More likely, you're better off just changing couldn't be able to to couldn't.
